# clear all property values using groovy script

Tags: groovy, soapui

Could anyone please help me with the groovy code to clear all property values for properties created in the datasink step.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me :

```
def datasink = testCase.testSteps["DataSink"]

String[] props = new String[datasink.getPropertyCount()]
props = datasink.getPropertyNames();



for (int i=0;i<props.size();i++)
{
    datasink.setPropertyValue(props[i],"")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
datasink = tcontext.testCase.getTestStepByName("DataSink");
datasink.clearPropertyValues();
```

Answer (score -1):

I only paste here, what works for me.

```
def datasink = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("DataSink");
//log.info datasink.getName()
datasink.clearPropertyValues();
```